# How to calculate list of needed java modules with jdeps?

Tags: java, tomcat, java-module, jlink, jdeps

I'm basically working with a tomcat webapp that has a complex structure, with many jars and classes at several locations and I want to generate a JRE with `jlink` and its `--add-modules` option in order to reduce the weight and attack surface of the binaries I use.

To clarify, if I include all modules with `jlink --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH` everything runs smoothly.

I've given this a few attempts:

### 1) run `jdeps` on whole dir

The target I need to analyse is a classic tomcat structure, which contains jars and classes at several locations.

```
> tree -L 1 /usr/local/tomcat/                                                                                                                  
├── LICENSE
├── NOTICE
├── RELEASE-NOTES
├── bin
├── conf
├── db.sh
├── favicon.ico
├── lib
├── logs
├── run
├── save.sh
├── start.sh
├── stop.sh
├── temp
├── webapps
└── work

> find . -name "*.jar" -o -name "*.class" | wc -l                                                                                             
     938
```

I've been trying to use jdeps in several ways but the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jdeps.html) are not super helpfull. Below is the only command that returned something looking like what I'd expect:

```
> jdeps --recursive --print-module-deps --ignore-missing-deps /usr/local/tomcat/
java.base,java.compiler,java.desktop,java.management,java.naming,java.scripting,java.sql
```

That kind of works as expected, but it seems to only take the classes into account. Without `--print-module-deps` I get a whole bunch of unknown dependencies like this

```
com.my.app -> org.eclipse.jgit.diff  not found
```

Even though the dependecy is properly installed at `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.jgit-5.10.0.202012080955-r.jar`.

As an obvious consequence, there are a lot of unlisted needed modules, and when executing the app with the custom JRE, I get errors because of the missing java modules.

### 2) Run jdeps on each jar/class file of the directory

I've tested runnning jdeps on every single jar to add the missing modules, even though a more direct / efficient approach with `jdeps` would be better.

The `find . -name "*.jar" -o -name "*.class" | xargs jdeps --print-module-deps --ignore-missing-deps` seems to do the trick on this basic usecase, but when applied to the bigger tomcat project, there still are runtime exceptions so I think the `ignore-missing-deps` makes it pointless.

[image: terminal screenshot]

### 3) Run jdeps on directory, providing all jar files to the classpath option of jdeps

Not being sure if `jdeps` is made to run on a full tomcat directory like that, I tried providing all jars to the `-cp` classpath option of jdeps, and it looks like it gets rid of some of the "not found" entries (262 => 43). Adding the classes makes no difference.

I still need to use `--ignore-missing-deps` in conjuction with `--print-module-deps` an a tail -1 to ignore the handfull of "split package" warnings

```bash
# run jdeps on directory (might need `apk -U add findutils` on alpine)
jdeps --multi-release 17 --recursive -cp "$(find . -name "*.jar" -printf "%h/*\n" | sort -u | paste -sd ":")" --ignore-missing-deps --print-module-deps ./  | tail -1
```

Using this output, I can go from the original full list of 68 java modules to only 17, gaining approximately 22MB. *Not sure about the attack surface, but I've seen better results on weigh reduction!*

This is still unperfect, for example I figured out that the app uses the `jar://` [FileSystemProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html). There is no specific `import` in the java class, so jdeps can't know that the app need the `jdk.zipfs` module to mount jars...

### Conclusion

Not confident about my binary;

Why does jdeps still gives me `not found` errors and `split package` warnings, how can I fix that?

Comment: The JRE also needs to bring the classes needed by tomcat itself.

Comment: Yes, in my example `/usr/local/tomcat/` actually contains all of tomat's jars (mainly in the lib dir I believe), so running jdeps on that dir should include tomcat's needed modules, as well as the webapp's modules.